# Add user to SharePoint group using Power Automate

Tags: http, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I would like to use Power Automate to add a user in as a member to a SharePoint Site using HTTP request.

The flow continues to fail on me and I'm wondering if anyone managed to do this successfully in the past?

I got the Group ID from :

> https://{org name}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site name}/_api/web/id

I have attached included the input and output of the HTTP Request (within flow) below

**Raw Inputs**

```
{
"host": {
    "connectionReferenceName": "shared_sharepointonline",
    "operationId": "HttpRequest"
},
"parameters": {
    "dataset": "https://{REDACTED}.sharepoint.com/",
    "parameters/method": "POST",
    "parameters/uri": "_api/web/sitegroups(547ea631-f9d4-411a-a3f5-8af3d5e6225b)/Users",
    "parameters/headers": {
        "accept": "application/json;odata.metadata=none",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "parameters/body": "{'LoginName':'i:0#.f|membership|{REDACTED}@{REDACTED}.com'}"
}
```

}

**Raw Outputs**

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"headers": {
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "x-ms-request-id": "cb6ab59f-909a-2000-ac2f-2217e416179a",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
    "Set-Cookie": "{REDACTED};Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-we.azconn-we.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite={REDACTED}24;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-we.azconn-we.p.azurewebsites.net",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
    "Date": "{TIME & DATE}",
    "Content-Length": "457",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Expires": "-1"
},
"body": {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "The expression \"web/sitegroups(547ea631-f9d4-411a-a3f5-8af3d5e6225b)/Users\" is not valid.\r\nclientRequestId: 1cc16a39-7d9c-4290-b07d-4c7329611fb8\r\nserviceRequestId: cb6ab59f-909a-2000-ac2f-2217e416179a",
    "source": "https://{REDACTED}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/sitegroups(547ea631-f9d4-411a-a3f5-8af3d5e6225b)/Users",
    "errors": [
        "-1",
        "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
    ]
}
```

}

The error I get is:

"The expression "web/sitegroups(547ea631-f9d4-411a-a3f5-8af3d5e6225b)/Users" is not valid.
clientRequestId: 1cc16a39-7d9c-4290-b07d-4c7329611fb8
serviceRequestId: cb6ab59f-909a-2000-ac2f-2217e416179a"

This makes me think the group ID is incorrect. Can someone please advise if this is incorrect or if I have maybe formatted the uri incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the body like this:

```
  {
                    '__metadata': {
                    // Type that you are modifying.
                    'type': 'SP.User'
                },
                    'LoginName': '<<User Login Name>>'
                }
```